# .htaccess Regex to rewrite path

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a very specific requirement and I pretty much suck at regular expressions to put it bluntly.

A program generates images of various sizes and puts them in a folder which is the same name as the image, the various generated images then get a new name based on their dimensions.

eg: /assets/images/waterlilly/0800x0600.jpg,/assets/images/waterlilly/0400x0300.jpg

Due to SEO the filenames are rather undesirable... so I thought if the src attribute of the image tag could be /assets/images/0800x0600/waterlilly.jpg I could "simply" write a regex for a htaccess RewriteRule...

And of course changing the programming of the tool that resizes the images is not currently an option (sadly)

So the regex i have is:

```
(.*?)+/[0-9]+x[0-9]+/(.*?)+\.(.*?)+
```

for my test file "/assets/images/0800x0600/waterlilly.jpg",which the regex matches, how do I get the following?

```
$1 = /assets/images/
$2 = 0800x0600
$3 = waterlilly
$4 = jpg
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
^(.+?)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+x[0-9]+)\.(.*)$
```

And this is the RewriteRule that will for you:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+x[0-9]+)\.(.*)$ /$1/$3/$2.$4 [L]
```

Comment: I accepted your answer even though it didnt actually work as I expected, though it pointed me in the right direction and helped me come up with a regex that worked.

here the working regex:

    `^((.*?)+)([0-9]+x[0-9]+)/([^.]+)(.*)$ /$1$3/$4$5 [L]`

Comment: Thanks and feel free to tell me what answer worked for you so that I can provide that as an edit to help future visitors.